# Error during running application

Tags: android, stack-overflow, tabactivity

In my Android application's main Activity is a `tabActivity` and one of the tab contains another Tab activity. I load the 2nd activity with different views.

There is an error on loading the Application on the emulator.

```
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.text.Styled.measureText(Styled.java:430)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.text.Layout.measureText(Layout.java:1655)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.text.Layout.getLineMax(Layout.java:689)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:340)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4150)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1480)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3138)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.ExpandableListView.dispatchDraw(ExpandableListView.java:229)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2584)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
03-11 16:28:46.463: E/AndroidRuntime(23736):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewR
```

Comment: post your code for more details

Comment: So , www.Whatyoury.com

Comment: Nirav, your link is _dead_ :)

Comment: I think your loop is executing multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Thrown when the depth of the stack of the running program exceeds some platform or VM specific limit. Typically, this will occur only when a program becomes infinitely recursive, but it can also occur in correctly written (but deeply recursive) programs.
[More Details](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely in your child activity you are trying to load the first activity again, which loads the second activity, which again loads the first activity and so on, leading to recursion and your app dies because it reaches the memory limit, applied by the OS.